# Where namespace reside in kubernetes architecture

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

I am confused that where namespace comes in k8s architecture?

I mean it is part of cluster itself or inside worker node or in master node (Control panel).

So there is one k8s cluster, inside the cluster one control panel and multiple worker nodes are there.

Now question is that namespace is in cluster or in control panel or in worker nodes?

I thought only worker nodes have namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes components and Kubernetes mechanisms are two different concepts. Kubernetes components are those which you need to have for keeping your cluster running while mechanisms are used for enhancing or for controlling the functioning of your cluster. Kubernetes controllers will have control over these mechanisms and like components they don't belong to a particular plane.

Namespace is just a mechanism for isolating groups of resources within a cluster or you can also consider it as a mechanism used for logical grouping of the resources.

Below are the official documents on Kubernetes components and namespace you can go through this for more information.

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/

[2] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/

Comment: Ok, so can we have multiple control panel (master node) in multiple namespace in one cluster?

Comment: In general a single controller or master node can control all the namespaces but when configuring HA for your cluster you will be having multiple control plane(master node)  which will be synced together.